# Programacion Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

Cordial Saludo,

Soy nuevo con Access manejo una base de datos de una entidad de salud y todo lo ingreso en Excel, lo que quiero es crear un programa donde pueda ir metiendo los datos y me diga si el paciente ya tiene esa especialidad se le muestre un mensaje y  sino lo deje guardar, tengo ya avanzado el proyecto pero me falta la parte de darle acciones a los botones.

busque tutoriales pero no logro orientarme a ver si me orientan.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A que te referis con darle acciones a los botones? a poner los eventos?

Comment: bueno cuando consulto un numero de identificacion del paciente quiero que me diga si esta registrado me cargue los datos de la base de datos, si no esta que me salga mensaje de que no esta registrado y poderlo ingresar, como cada ´paciente tiene varias especialidades cx de columna urologia que la especialidad tambien diga ya existe y evitar el registro de la misma especialidad es como evitar duplicados, un paciente puede tener varias especialidades pero un paciente no puede tener varias especialidades de la misma si me hago entender.

Comment: si. eso se entiende. pero que parte no podes hacer? porque eso que estas buscando es bastante codigo. Tenes que tratar de ser mas especifico, mostrar que hiciste, y donde tuviste problemas.

Comment: solo necesito validar la cedula si esta me traiga los datos y si no esta letrero de que no existe, solamente he hecho lo de mostrar los mensajes porque no se como traer los datos.

Comment: podes mostrar lo que hiciste y lo que intentaste? asi te vamos a poder ayudar mejor.

Comment: Private Sub Comando126_Click()
If IsNull(DLookup("[IDENTIFICACION]", "[PACIENTE]", "[IDENTIFICACION]=form!txt_buscar.value")) = False Then

MsgBox "Paciente no se encuentra ingresado"

Else


If IsNull(DLookup("[REQUERIMIENTO]", "[PACIENTE]", "[REQUERIMIENTO]=form!txt_req.value")) = False Then

MsgBox "Especialidad ya Existe"

Else

MsgBox "Especialidad no Existe"

End If
End If
End
End Sub

Comment: eso no mas quiero es traer los datos pero no se como.

Comment: puede ser que tu pregunta sea, como lleno los datos de mi formulario cuando el usuario ingresa un valor en un campo?

Comment: exacto que sea el de identificacion, si no hay que diga no existe

Comment: o sea.. necesitas otra ventana donde ingresar algun dato, hacer el lookup, fijarte que devolvio (eso lo sabes por tu codigo) y de ser asi llamar a la otra ventana con ese registro para que lo muestre en la pantalla.. es eso? si es asi, ya tenes por donde investigar ;)

Comment: si miras la foto que puse quiero q ahi en el mismo formulario e buscado y nada que me da.

Comment: No se si te sirve, pero una vez que hayas comprobado si existe o no el paciente y la especialidad, en caso de que sí existan, podrías a lo mejor filtrar el formulario para que muestre solo ese registro, o [abrir otro con los datos que quieres.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/access/concepts/forms-design/apply-a-filter-when-opening-a-form-or-report)

Comment: si amigo pero no lo se hacer llevo 2 meses leyendo y probando y nada, soy nuevo no se de programacion. gracias por la respuesta.